# Python processes, threads as compared to PHPs for web hosting

Tags: php, python, apache, lamp, uwsgi

On a traditional LAMP stack it's easy to stack up quite a few web sites one a single VPS and get very decent performance, with the VPS serving lots of concurrent requests, thanks to the web server using processes and threads making best use of multi cores cpu despite PHP (as python) being single threaded.

Is the management of processes and threads the same on a python web stack (uwsgi + ngnix) ? On such a properly configured python stack, is it possible to achieve same result as the LAMP stack and stack several sites on same VPS with good reliability and performance making best use of cpu resources ? Does the GIL make it any different ?

Comment: Your question is nigh un-answerable: 1. CGI and WSGI are wholly different beasts. 2. Any two applications are going to have wholly different performance characteristics and resource requirements, even if they're both written in the same language. 3. Shared hosting is the devil in any form.

Answer (score 0):

the problem of scaling is always the shared data . ie how your processes are going to communicate with each other so it's not a python (GIL) problem